# Global objects across various objects in scala

Tags: scala

I have various defined objects in different scala files

for example:

```
var global:myClass=new myClass("1")

/*...Object1.scala..*/
Object Object1()
{global=new myClass("2")}

/*...Object2.scla..*/
Object Object2()
{global=new myClass("3")}
```

I need to define an object which is global across all these scala objects?

How to do this in scala?

Comment: First thing is learn Scala syntax.

Comment: The sole world *global* should make you so scared and disgusted to have pronounced it that you regret asking the question. Whatever, you meant with *global*, this does not smell good

Comment: Ok. do you have any suggestion for above delimma..what should I use? resources?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean and what your goal is. Why do you want to have a global mutable variable, and why do you want to change the value inside different objects; what's the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your example, from syntax to semantics. I'll keep it as close as I can to what you tried for strictly didactic purposes.
In order to define a "global" variable", you want to create an object with a  variable and this variable will be global , because there will ever be one version of this object.

```
scala> class myClass(val myValue : String){}
defined class myClass

scala> object G { var global : myClass = new myClass("1") }
defined object G

scala> G.global.myValue
res0: String = 1

scala> object Object1{G.global = new myClass("2")}
defined object Object1

scala> object Object2{G.global = new myClass("3")}
defined object Object2

scala>  G.global.myValue
res1: String = 1

scala> Object1
res2: Object1.type = Object1$@3d630b38

scala> G.global.myValue
res3: String = 2

scala> Object2
res4: Object2.type = Object2$@6a01c21

scala> G.global.myValue
res5: String = 3
```

A second problem with your example is that you try to use object definition to get work done, what is not a good way. The code inside an object id not executed when it is defined, but you can get this code executed by "stating" it. This is not recommended and is here just to show how to make your initial trial work.
It doesn't matter in which files your code is defined, as long as everywhere where you use your global variable, you import the object.